# Permissions - How to remove folder permissions for one person in a group

Tags: permissions, groups

I want to know if there is a way to set up permissions so that if a group has permissions for a folder, that there is a way to remove a user that belongs to that group from a specific folder inside the folder that the group has permissions to.

The hierarchy goes something like this:

Folder A (group x has permissions for this folder)

- Folder A1 (I want to remove permissions for this folder for one specific user of group x)
- Folder A2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say if you are using code or just in general...

The process is the same, regardless. Break inheritance on A1 and then set permissions are desired.

The guidance is to minimize number of uniquely-permissioned items in a farm. The maintenance of permissions is one of the most least-understood concepts by end users.

Comment: I'm not using code. What if I want to still give group x access to folder A1, and the specific group member is still a member of that group?

Comment: Then that person would still have permissions. You would have to create a second group that contains all of the members of that group EXCEPT the person you do not want to see it.

Comment: Unfortunately you can only set permissions on the site collection, site, library/List level. There is no way you can set unique permmision for a specific folder in a document library unless using code which I am not sure how. So, I agree with Lori - create two groups.

Comment: Yes, you can set permissions on a folder.